# Filter dropdown on edit view in Sonata Admin Bundle

Tags: sonata-admin, symfony-sonata

First of all, say that I guess this this question has already been resolved, but my english does not allow me to find the answer.

I have a "problem" with Sonata, when I have to associate something with a lot of results (eg: assign an exiting product to an invoice) Sonata generates a very large dropdown list. **Is there a way to filter this list?**

Thank you!

Comment: Did this ever get resolved? Information floating around the net is still very bare  about this

Comment: See my answer below. If you think others can benefit from it maybe ask the question yourself (with better english maybe) so i can answer it and you can accept it as this question seems pretty dead

Answer (score 1):

You should use the form types provided by sonata.

If you want the list of all invoices that you can filter by typing in the select input use `sonata_type_model`

If you have a lot of invoices and don't want to load them all use `sonata_type_model_autocomplete`

https://sonata-project.org/bundles/admin/master/doc/reference/form_types.html

If your `sonata_type_model` input doesn't let you filter you should verify that your version of sonata admin uses select2 and is properly configured to use it

```
#config.yml

sonata_admin:
    options:
        use_select2:    true
```

Answer (score 0):

Although that is kinda old question, nevertheless I came here when I was googling this theme. So, my solution is:

```
protected function configureFormFields(FormMapper $formMapper)
{
    $formMapper
        ->add('city', null, [
            'query_builder' => function(EntityRepository $repo) {
                // Here you should create and return a DQL query
                // that will filter data the way you want
                return $repo
                        ->createQueryBuilder('city')
                        ->where('city.country_code = \'US\'')
                        ->orderBy('city.name', 'ASC')
                ;
            }
        ])
    ;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can have several options:

- You can use `$formMapper->add('invoice', 'sonata_type_model_list');` which will give you a nice widget for selecting an invoice to associate.
- You can use [GenemuFormBundle](https://github.com/genemu/GenemuFormBundle) to display [Select2](http://ivaynberg.github.io/select2/) library widgets. Very easy to integrate. Just use `genemu_jqueryselect2_entity` type and set `class` attribute to your entity.